# How to prevent dwm from tag switching when launching Skype

Tags: skype, dwm

I'm running dwm and Skype included in it's tag rules:

```c
static const Rule rules[] = {
    /* class      instance    title       tags mask     isfloating   monitor */
    /* snip */
    { "Skype",  NULL,       NULL,       1 << 6,       False,        -1 },
    /* snip */
};
```

Problem is that when I launching Skype dwm always switching currently selected tags to Skype tag to show itself. While all other application in such case just silently load and doesn't affect selected tags.

Comment: As far as I know, this is due to something that Skype actually does (not dwm). For example, I have the same problem with Steam, but no other clients (of which I am aware).